# Estimate standard error from given hazard ratios and total event number but not person year

Tags: meta-analysis

I'm doing a meta-analysis and I want to pool the Hazard ratios. One of the studies presented the hazard ratio and total number of events. However, person-year and 95% CI wasn't provided. Is there any methods to estimate the standard error or the 95% CI?